# Почему при обновлении файлов на сервере не происходят изменения?

Tags: cms, веб-сервер, opencart

Доброго времени. Случилась такая проблема. попросили подправить сайт на open cart. Вначале хотел подключить свои стили но после изменения header.tpl не каких обновлений на сервере не произошло. Файл с изменениями но на собранных страницах нет изменений.

Ладно тогда я решил докинуть изменения в подключенный css. И все та же история. В файле имения есть а на в source все тот же старый файл. Страницу перезагружал уже раз 7 так что это не кеш. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кэш – это набор наиболее используемых данных, которые хранятся специальным образом, благодаря чему извлечение информации из кэша сайта происходит намного быстрее, чем её запрос из непосредственного хранилища.

Сначала попробуйте очистить кеш своего браузера, или зайти с другого браузера. Может быть страница закеширована у Вас в браузере?

Если нет, то скорее всего она закеширована на сервере.

Поэтому для того, чтобы увидеть результаты своих правок на мониторе, необходимо очистить кэш OpenCart.

Подключитесь к FTP сайта, зайдите в каталог где расположен движок, в папке system/cache удалите все файлы кроме index.html. Возможно там есть еще какой-нибудь кеш, который нужно удалить при правке шаблона.

Comment: в админке opencart есть возможность очищать любой кэш

Comment: В system есть только папка cache_mfp которая пуста. Но рядом с папкой system есть папка vqmod в которой есть забитая папка vqcache но судя по всему это что-то не относящееся к oc.

Comment: @tCode можете подсказать куда зайти для очистки?

Comment: @Drop, в админке в меню есть раздел "Очистка кеша"

Comment: @tCode Облазил менюшку, не нашел.

Comment: В htacess нашел пару строк 
`## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On

ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"

ExpiresByType text/css тАЬaccess plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType text/plain тАЬaccess plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/gif тАЬaccess plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>`